# How to set Y axis with equal interval in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I know this question has been asked before on StackOverflow. However, I have slightly different ask so **please read it before you mark it as Duplicate**.

I am trying to set y-axis to 0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128.... also, the spacing between those tickPoints should be equal. I have tried setting various interval but it didn't help below is my code.

```
 $("#ClickSmu_man").click(function () {
        var theModal = $("#ModalSmu_man").modal({
            show: false
        });

        Highcharts.chart('container_man', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'In Progress weekly pending Avg. Age per DE Manager Count'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    <?php foreach($smu_top_manager as $topma){ ?>
                        '<?php echo $topma['name']; ?>',                
                    <?php } ?>                    
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                tickInterval: 1,

                title: {
                    text: 'Platform'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [
                    {
                    name: 'Age',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $age_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'asr9k_px',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $asr9k_px_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'asr9k_x64',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $asr9k_x64_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'crs_px',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $crs_px_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'ncs5500',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $ncs5500_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'ncs5500_sysadmin',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $s5500_sysadmin_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'ncs5k',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $ncs5k_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'ncs6k',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $ncs6k_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'xr12000',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $xr12000_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'xrv9k',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $xrv9k_manager); ?>],
                    },
                    {
                    name: 'xrv9k_sysadmin',
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',', $xrv9k_sysadmin_manager); ?>],
                    }                        
                ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Creating a working demo of your code on online fiddler helps people to answer your question, quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [yAxis.tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions) to define ticks in your chart.

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0,2,4,8,16,32,64],
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/f94hdLqt/

If you want to set ticks dynamically, you can use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner).

Comment: Thank you that Helps @morganfree Is there any way I can set equal space between all those tickPositions?

Comment: You need a logarithmic scale - set xAxis.type = 'logarithmic' and you need to map tickPosition to Math.log10(x) where x is the tick position in a linear axis - http://jsfiddle.net/ggfq5jko/ Also, if you have a logarithmic scale your values must be bigger than 0.

Comment: Thank you @Morganfree it solved my issue. I have edited your answer with your correct solution. Thanks again.